# get source via html script tag causes net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on some Android devices

Tags: android, html, reactjs, google-chrome, django-templates

below screen capture is chrome inspect console, inspecting some user's Android device.
[image]

I definitely have no idea about
why 1 or 2 out of almost hundred Android devices cause net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

below code is in my django template html file.

```
...
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4/dist/smoothscroll.min.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>
```

not only unpkg react related src, but polyfill, static.ads-twitter and google-analytics also have same error 'net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED'

does anyone could help me out how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This blog helped me once : https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-name-not-resolved-error/

Comment: Thank you for the ref but that expect users to change their setting, so...

Answer (score 0):

resolved by adding 'react' and 'react-dom' as static files

[image]